# the name "place" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

So basically I've declared the array int[,] place, but when I try to assign values to it into loading of the form, it says it

> does not exist in the current context

...and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

```
int pbNum = 0;
int stepFrame = 0;
int stepLeft;
int[,] place; 
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player.Location = new Point(100,Ground.Top - 64);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    {
        place(0, pbNum) = pb.Left; 
    pbNum += 1;
    }
    this.Text = pbNum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: 1) you have not initialized that variable;
2) use square brackets: place[0, pbNum] = ...

Comment: @Tanruss1 [So why are you using your array like a method instead?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Comment: @JleruOHeP thank you, I'm not quite used to c# yet, and this is my first project for a class

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is. It is not a function but array

```
foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    place[0, pbNum] = pb.Left; 
    pbNum += 1;
}
```

I have changed the `()` to `[]`